# While Looping Query gives Exception out of memory

Tags: sql-server

I need to loop through all the data from the table result. For example select result got a column call Quantity. I need the Column value to do the looping. But I get out of memory exception during looping.

```
DECLARE @Qty int
DECLARE @COUNT int
DECLARE @itemcode nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @GRNNo nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @UOM nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @Weight decimal(18,2)
DECLARE @PurchaseDate datetime
DECLARE @Cost decimal(18,2)

SET @COUNT = 1

WHILE exists (Select * from #tempOpening) 
BEGIN
  SELECT top 1 @Qty = QTY, @itemcode = ItemCode, @GRNNo = GRNNo, @Cost=UnitPrice
    , @PurchaseDate=PurchaseDate, @UOM=UOM, @Weight = Weight
  from #tempOpening order by ItemCode

  print @Qty
  print @itemcode
  WHILE @Qty>0
  BEGIN
    SELECT @itemcode AS ItemCode,
      'D'+RIGHT('00000000'+CAST(@COUNT as nvarchar(8)),8) as SerialNo,
      @PurchaseDate PurchaseDate,
      '' TestData,
      ''TestRemark,
      'HQ' Location,
      @UOM BuyType,
      1 qty,
      @Weight Weight,
      @Cost Cost,
      0 PackingFee,
      '' Remarks,
      @GRNNo as GRNNO, 
      null returnDate,
      'SATO' createdBy,
      GETDATE() createDate,
      null CreatedDate,
      null ModifiedDate,
      null SaNo,
      @Qty OriginalQty,
      @Weight

    SET @COUNT = @COUNT+1
    SET @Qty = @Qty -1
  END
  print 'Out loop'
  DELETE FROM #tempOpening where ItemCode= @itemcode and GRNNo = @GRNNo
END
```

Comment: Is it getting stuck in the inner loop or the outer loop?

Comment: any particular reason why you are using `LOOP`  and not set-based solution ?

Comment: Your loop will go forever if either of ItemCode or GRNNo are null

Comment: @DaleBurrell my loop will end, if i export the result to file it work.

Comment: @Squirrel because i need to insert into a detail table with a unqie code

Comment: Well you must be trying to process too many rows in one go if you're getting out of memory.

Comment: @WoonLai That's not a good reason to use a loop. You can still do it as a set.

Comment: @WoonLai, How many rows you have in #tempOpening table?

Comment: @HasanMahmood got 4752 rows

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn i will try to separate out the data

Comment: @WoonLai, what is your max Qty value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: if this work for you I can explain all the things:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Qty int
DECLARE @COUNT int
DECLARE @itemcode nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @GRNNo nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @UOM nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @Weight decimal(18,2)
DECLARE @PurchaseDate datetime
DECLARE @Cost decimal(18,2)

--Decalre basic table 
DECLARE @tempOpening TABLE 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    QTY int,
    ItemCode nvarchar(30),
    GRNNo nvarchar(30),
    UnitPrice decimal(18,2),
    PurchaseDate datetime,
    UOM nvarchar(30),
    Weight decimal(18,2)
)

DECLARE @site_value INT;
SET @site_value = 0;

--insert test data into basic table
WHILE @site_value <= 4752 
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO @tempOpening(QTY, ItemCode, GRNNo, UnitPrice, PurchaseDate, UOM, Weight)
   VALUES(10,'Code100' + CAST(@site_value AS VARCHAR(10)),'GRNNo',10.2,GETDATE(), 'Unit',5.5);
   SET @site_value = @site_value + 1;
END;

--created a new table for avoiding inner loop
DECLARE @tblQty TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    RowNo   INT
)
DECLARE @maxQty INT 
SELECT @maxQty =MAX(QTY) FROM @tempOpening
DECLARE @i INT = 1;

--insert data into Qty table with max Qty, this table data will help us to do dynamic query with joining 
WHILE @i <= @maxQty
BEGIN   
   INSERT INTO @tblQty(RowNo)
   VALUES(@i)
   SET @i = @i + 1;
END;

SET @COUNT = 1

--created a temp table to insert all inner loop data, this is the final output data
DECLARE @tblAllData TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ItemCode NVARCHAR(30),
    SerialNo NVARCHAR(30),
    PurchaseDate DATETIME,
    TestData NVARCHAR(100),
    TestRemark NVARCHAR(100),
    Location NVARCHAR(100),
    BuyType NVARCHAR(30),
    Qty INT,
    Weight DECIMAL(18,2),
    Cost DECIMAL(18,2),
    PackingFee  INT,
    Remarks NVARCHAR(200),
    GRNNO NVARCHAR(30),
    ReturnDate DATETIME NULL,
    CreatedBy NVARCHAR(100),
    CreateDate DATETIME NULL,
    CreatedDate DATETIME NULL,
    ModifiedDate DATETIME NULL,
    SaNo    INT NULL,
    OriginalQty INT
)

DECLARE C CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT QTY, ItemCode, GRNNo, UnitPrice , PurchaseDate, UOM, Weight from @tempOpening  

OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @Qty , @itemcode , @GRNNo , @Cost , @PurchaseDate, @UOM , @Weight 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN

    --insert into the all table data
    INSERT INTO @tblAllData(ItemCode, SerialNo, PurchaseDate, TestData, TestRemark, Location, BuyType, Qty, Weight, Cost, PackingFee, Remarks, GRNNO, ReturnDate, 
    CreatedBy, CreateDate, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, SaNo, OriginalQty)

    SELECT TOP (@Qty) @itemcode AS ItemCode,
      'D'+RIGHT('00000000'+CAST((@COUNT + tbl.RowNo) as nvarchar(8)),8) as SerialNo,
      @PurchaseDate PurchaseDate, '' TestData, ''TestRemark, 'HQ' Location,  @UOM BuyType, 1 qty, @Weight,  @Cost Cost, 0 PackingFee, '' Remarks,
      @GRNNo as GRNNO,  null returnDate, 'SATO' createdBy, GETDATE() createDate, null CreatedDate, null ModifiedDate, null SaNo, @Qty - tbl.RowNo AS OriginalQty
      FROM @tblQty tbl
      ORDER BY tbl.RowNo

    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @Qty , @itemcode , @GRNNo , @Cost , @PurchaseDate, @UOM , @Weight   

END

CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C    

SELECT * FROM @tblAllData
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i will follow your logic to modify abit.